# Using derived class's EntityManger on field's initialization of parent's class

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

We're using JEE with CDI and EclipseLink.
We have an abstract class and a child class extending it.
I want on the creation to initiate the **entityName** field with JPA's entity name, but in this point of the object creation the **entityManager** injected in **Cat** class is still Null.

I don't want to initialize **entityName** in @PostConstruct method of AbstractClass, as this way the initial value will be empty string, and if child class will want to use **entityName**, as you see below, it'll get the initial empty string value and not the updated one.
Is there a way to overcome this?

```
   public abstract class AbstractClass<T, P> {

        protected final String entityName = getEntityManager().getMetamodel().entity(entityClass).getName();

        protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();
...
}

    @ApplicationScoped
    public class Cat extends AbstractClass<Cat,Integer>
    {
        private final String queryName= entityName + ".findBy";

        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;


        @Override
        public EntityManager getEntityManager() 
        {
            return this.entityManager;
        }

    ...
    }
```